# Popover in chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Bootstrap popover isn't working in chrome extension, although it works in a normal webpage. Is there something that keeps extensions from having popovers? I've also already tried changing data-toggle to manual or focus. They are all in the same folder that I have loaded as an unpacked extension on chrome://extensions, including bootstrap, jquery, and tether minified js files.

popup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'left'});   
});
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "tether.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Popover Example</h3>
    <a href="#" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="manual" data-content="Hi">Click me</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Popover",
  "description": "Make a popover.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The script file should be in the extension directory and linked locally from there.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: @wOxxOm Considering the question _hasn't_ been edited, I'm not sure what you were referring to.

Comment: Er, really? Well, stylesheet, obviously, not the script.